# Incremental Update DB field

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update a current DB field value by adding or subtracting a numeric value. I have reviewed "suggested answers" and did not find a solution to my problem.  The field in my DB is title "credits" and it has a default value of "0."  The DB engine designated is InnoDB. I use procedural php coding and following is my code at present:

Defined variables

```
    $id=$_SESSION['user_id'];  //id number for user
    $amount=$_POST['Amount']; //value of charges 12 character string
    $amount=ltrim($amount, '0'); //eliminates leading 0's
    $credit=$amount/1000; //converts value to credits
    $credit=number_format($credit, 2);  //formats credits with two decimal points
```

I then establish a DB connection  and perform the following queries

```
    $q="select credits from registration WHERE user_id=$id";
    $r=mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
    $update="UPDATE registration SET credits = credits + $credit WHERE user_id=$id";
```

If I "echo" the variables I see all of the values but the "update" fails.  Using procedural php coding, what needs to be revised to incrementally update the "credits" field?

Comment: What is the type of the column `credits` and what error do you get?

Comment: the column is a smallint(7) and I did not receive an error message.

Comment: Not sure, but looks like you're trying to save a float as an integer

Comment: Thank you Alfwed and Bob.  That was one issue I overlooked.  I changed the column type to decimal(7,2) but it still does not work.

Comment: Just `echo $update` before executing it and paste it here, that way we can see what's wrong with the actual SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//**i hope this helps**

<?php
$id=$_SESSION['user_id'];  //id number for user
$amount=$_POST['Amount']; //value of charges 12 character string
$amount=ltrim($amount, '0'); //eliminates leading 0's
$credit=$amount/1000; //converts value to credits
$credit=number_format($credit, 2);  //formats credits with two decimal points

$credits; // the credits from query select will be stored here

/* edit with your database parameters */
       $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);

       if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
          echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
          exit();
       }

       mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8");

if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("select credits from registration WHERE user_id=?"))
{
 $stmt -> bind_param("i", $id); //'i' means that ? is an integer value, and $id is the parameter for this value
 $stmt -> execute();
 $stmt -> bind_result($credits);
 $stmt -> fetch();
 $stmt -> close();

 $total=$credits+$credit;
 if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE registration SET credits = ? WHERE user_id=?"))
 {
  $stmt->bind_param("di",$total,$id);
  $stmt->execute();
  echo 'oki doki';
  $stmt->close();
 }

}

?>
```

Comment: Dante, I had decided to do the "$total=$credits+$credit" approach as you are suggesting and your response has inspired me to expand my knowledge.  I really do need to learn more about Prepared Statements and Bound Parameters.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For closure, I wanted to provide the coding that fixed my problem and it may help anyone that views this posting.  I do believe that Dante's solution using "prepared statements" is best but here is how I resolved my problem.

lines of code add:

```
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $cr= sprintf ("%s", $row["credits"]);  //assign results to a variable

    $ttl=$cr+$credit;
```

Revised the update query to:

```
    $update="UPDATE registration SET credits=$ttl WHERE user_id=$id";  
    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $update) or trigger_error("Query: $update\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
```

This worked just fine and I needed the $ttl and $credit variables in my messages to the user.  I hope this helps.